# Context Root mapping and Spring MVC

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I have 2 Controllers which are redirected to the same jsp.

```
//Controller1
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/user")
public class UserController {
    @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String defaultPage(Model model){
         return "home";
    }
}

//Controller2
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
public class HomeController {
    @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String HomePage(Model model){
         return "home";
    }
}
```

now on "home" view page, I have below script.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="resources/js/myTutorModule.js">     
</script>
```

This line is rendered as below in browser..
controller 1
localhost:8080/myApp/user/resources/js/myTutorModule.js

controller 2
localhost:8080/myApp/resources/js/myTutorModule.js

So only the 2nd one is working. Is there a way to handle this with out using JSP context root(I am planning to use angular JS and want to use html - no JSPs ). Any suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use JSTL tag library for URL parsing in the view pages instead of hardcoding the urls. Spring sometimes define the context of the page from the url its being browsed through. Lets say you are in the url **app/user/add** and **app/user/list** both of which uses the same js or css static resource.

Then if you refer to the static resource like **/resources/js/file.js**, Then the url resolved might differ as the roots of the urls are different in this case **/add/resources/js/file.js** and the later one **/list/resources/js/file.js** .This why some view pages might not be rendered correctly.

The solution is try using some taglib like JSTL. Define your static resources url as `<c:url>` variable tags and use them when ever you need to refer to static or dynamic resources. `<c:url>` always try to resolve the url from the root of the application that is the webcontent folder.

**Steps-**

1. Include jstl dependency to your project if you are using any build systems. or just include the jstl jar file if you are manually building the app.
2. Include the jstl tag lib to the jsp page you want to use the `<c:url>` tag in 
   `<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>`
3. Define url variable as `<c:url value="resources/js/myTutorModule.js" var="tutorModuleJs"/>`
4. Use the variable in the link ref 
   `<script type="text/javascript" src="${tutorModuleJs}"></script>`

You can refer to this [link](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jstl_core_url_tag.htm) to know more about JSTL tag library url tag

Comment: Chandan, Thanks for you suggestion. I was trying not to use JSPs. But it looks like there is no other option other than what your suggestion above. I mean, my inital idea was to  use of HTML + Angular js and Spring REST